# SQLAlchemy hangs while connecting to SQL Azure, but not always

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I have a django application, which is making use of SQLAlchemy to connect to a SQL Server instance on Windows Azure.  The app has worked perfectly for 3 months on a local SQL Server instance, and for over a month on an Azure instance.  The issues appeared this monday, after a week without any code changes.

The site uses:

- Python 2.7
- Django 1.6
- Apache/Nginx
- SQLAlchemy 0.9.3
- pyODBC 3.0.7
- FreeTDS

The application appears to lock up right after a connection is pulled out of the Pool (I have setup verbose logging at every point in the workflow).  I assumed this had something to do with the connections going stale.  So we tried making the pool_recycle incredibly short (5 secs), all the way up to an hour.  That did not help.

We also tried using the NullPool to force a new connection on every page view.  However that does not help either.  After about 15 minutes the site will completely lock up again (meaning no pages that use the database are viewable).

The weird thing is, half the computers that experience the "hang", will end up loading the page about 15 minutes later.

Has anyone had any experience with SQL Azure and SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround for this issue.  Please note that this is definitely not a fix, since the site worked perfectly fine before.  We could not determine what the actual issue is because SQL Azure has no error log (one of the 100 reasons I would suggest never considering SQL Azure over a real database server).

I got around the problem by turning off all Connection Pooling, at the application level, AND at the driver level.

Things started consistently working after making my `/etc/odbcinst.ini` look like:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
# Some installations may differ in the paths
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPReuse =
CPTimeout = 0
FileUsage = 1
Pooling = No
```

The key being setting CPTimeout (Connection Pool Timeout) to 0, and Pooling to `No`.  Just turning pooling off at the application level (in SQL Alchemy) did not work, only after setting it at the driver level did things start working smoothly.

I am now at 4 days without a problem after changing that setting.